# Floated divs pushed down on ie9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I'm having a problem in ie9 on the page header on this site: http://www.cheverellwood.co.uk/

The div containing the h1 tag is being pushed down on ie9 as well as the submenu on pages where it appears. It's fine in ie7 and ie8, firefox, safari and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IE9 specific hack to get it to display properly in IE9. Add the `\0` argument to your css class, e.g.

```
:root .test {color: green \0;}
```

See http://mynthon.net/howto/-/webdev/CSS-big-list-of-css-hacks.txt for a list of browser specific hacks.

Or use a conditional comment

`<!--[if IE]> Internet Explorer 9- <![endif]-->`

Comment: Cheers. My main problem though, is knowing what to change. Inspecting the element doesn't show any margin or undue positioning that I can see.